# Allowing bitcoind startup script to access daemon commands

Tags: bitcoind, daemon

I'm trying to create multiple full nodes on a single machine each using a different data directory and static ip's.

My directory layout is

> ~/bitcoin1
> ~/bitcoin2
> ~/bitcoin3

For each direcotry I have a bash script named btc(number) with this:

> !/bin/bash
> ~/bitcoin1/bitcoind -conf=~/bitcoin1/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

With the config files respectively stating the data directories and parameters.

My issue is whenever I try to run a command like "Getinfo", I have to pass the whole config file argument to the daemon like so:

> ~/bitcoin1/bitcoind -conf=~/bitcoin1/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf getinfo

How can I make my start up bash script allow the daemon commands as well?

I'd like to achieve this:

> ~/bitcoin1/./btc1 getinfo
>
> or btc1 stop

Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for the formatting. Never posted here before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add $1 to the end of the command in your script. This is more a general scripting question. Doesn't have much to do with bitcoin.

~/bitcoin1/bitcoind -conf=~/bitcoin1/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf $1